# nPoco - Get single object with nested data

Tags: c#, orm, repository-pattern, npoco

I have two Dto's:

```
[TableName("Address")]
    public class AddressDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Building { get; set; }
        public string Appartment { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string Floor { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }

[TableName("DistributionPoint")]
    public class DistributionPointDto
    {
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Reference(ReferenceType.Foreign, ColumnName = "AddressId", ReferenceMemberName = "Id")]
        public AddressDto Address { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I get DistributionPointDto with nested AddressDto using nPoco?
I have a generic repository for CRUD with method:

```
 public T FindById<T>(int id)
        {
           return _db.SingleById<T>(id);
        }
```

But, when I'm trying to get DistributionPointDto, AddressDto is `null`

Comment: What does you entity data mapping look like?  The link between the two tables(classes) may be missing or wrong.

Comment: I mapped using attributes in Dto

Comment: Start by getting all AddressDto to make sure it is not the ID that is the issue. The mapping may need to be refreshed if any changes were made. A common issue is the connection string is mapped to an older version of the database.  So check the connection string.

Comment: `public IQueryProviderWithIncludes<T> GetAll<T>()
        {
            return _db.Query<T>();
        }`  is Ok. I can include AddressDto when I get all DistributionPointDto's

Comment: Then the Id is not matching.  Is the Id column name "Id" or "AddressId"?  Is the Id in database a string or an integer?

Comment: In the database I have dbo.DistributionPoint with columns: Id(int), AddressId (int) and dbo.Address with column Id(int)

Comment: Why dos your class AddressDto have only Id and not AddressId?  Are you searching for Id or AddressId?

Answer (score 0):

Curious if you got your code to work, but I have found that you need to use Query instead of SingleById to include referenced properties, and then you can use an Include statement/clause, however I don't think generics work with this, you have to explicitly mention the referenced property name, which is AddressDTO for you.

```
_db.Query<DistributionPointDTO>()
  .Include(x => x.AddressDTO)
  .Where(x => x.Id == id).First();
```